# Write a partitioned matrix in rmarkdown

Tags: matrix, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to insert vertical and horizontal lines inside a matrix to divide it into 4 sections. I would like my matrix to look matrix 4.7 in Matrix Population Models by Dr. Caswell.  [image]
Please see my try below. How do I improve the code? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
$$A_{m,4} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} | & a_{1,3} & a_{1,n} \\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} | & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
   -----            | ----\\ 
  a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & a_{m,3} & a_{m,4}
 \end{pmatrix}$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following latex code in your RMD file:

```
$$A_{m,4} =
\left(
  \begin{array}{cc|cc}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,n} \\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
  \hline
  a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & a_{m,3} & a_{m,4}
\end{array} \right)$$
```

The result:

[image]